# How to send AJAX request from append element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have create a button, when i click on the button it's append a form. there are a dropdownlist in the form i have load all product name and value in the dropdownlist, now i want to send ajax request for specific product data from database. 
  [image: here is the picture]

if i add two or more append it's only show the first append form value.

Comment: Can you try, and explain your question better? It doesn't make much sense, also provide us with more code, what is appended where, how, where should the AJAX go, etc. Thanks

Comment: Question's a little unclear, but I guess you should add a JS event handler for the "change" event on the new dropdown, and then run the ajax to get the selected product details. Pretty standard stuff and there must be hundreds of examples of that online. What have you tried?  What issue are you facing exactly?

Comment: i'm edit my question and add picture for better understanding.

Comment: @Majeed add some code. Your question is not clear. Unable to understand where to make the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will work for you.

```
<!--JQuery Dynamic Part -->
      <div id="bul_container">
         <div id="bulk">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-3">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Main-Color</label>
                 <input type="text" name="color[]" class="form-control" required data-parsley-error-message="Enter Color Name or Code">
               </div>

             </div>
             <div class="col-md-2">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Order Quantity</label>
                 <input type="text" name="qty[]" class="form-control" required data-parsley-error-message="Enter Quantity">
               </div>
             </div>
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

var bulkn="<div class='row'>"+$('#bulk .row').first().html()+"</div>";
$('.add').click(function(){

        $('#bulk').append(bulkn);
        $('#bulk .row').last();

});
$('.remove').click(function(){
  if($('#bulk .row').length>1){
    $('#bulk .row').last().remove();
  }
  else{
   alert("You can't Remove this Row");
  }
});
```